# Call a function with mouseover. (Different options)

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, mouseover

i got this selector. Currently it calles a function when switch (click) on the different options. Now i wish to use another `function2()` is called when i only move the mouse over an option but not click on it. And when click on the option, `function1()` should be called. How to do that?

```
<select id = "nextGeneration" onchange="function1()" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen on mouse over?

Comment: Maybe just highlight some DOM elements.

Comment: This doesn't seem easily possible with plain JS. If you are flexible to consider jQuery do search likewise. There are lot of SO answers showing jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery?

```
<select id = "nextGeneration">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option> 
</select> 

<script>

$("#nextGeneration").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});

$("#nextGeneration").ready(function(){
    $("#nextGeneration").change(function(){
        alert("The select has been changed.");
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: `$('#nextGeneretor')` is used where you could just use `this` reference

Answer (score -1):

Using the `mouseover` event:

```js
function handleChange() {
    console.log('change')
}

function handleMouseover(e) {
    console.log('mouseover')
}
```

```html
<select onchange='handleChange()' onmouseover='handleMouseover(event)'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```